# How to use multiline flag in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to transform chunks of text into a database of single line entries database with regex. But I don't know why the regex group isn't recognized.
Maybe because the multiline flag isn't properly set.
I am a beginner at python.

```
import re
with open("a-j-0101.txt", encoding="cp1252") as f: 
    start=1
    ecx=r"(?P<entrcnt>[0-9]{1,3}) célébrités ou évènements"
    ec1=""
    nmx=r"(?P<ename>.+)\r\nAfficher le.*"
    nm1=""
    for line in f:
        if start == 1:
            out = open('AST0101.txt' + ".txt", "w", encoding="cp1252") #utf8 cp1252
            ec1 = re.search(ecx,line)
            out.write(ec1.group("entrcnt"))
            start=0
        out.write(r"\r\n")
        nm1 = re.search(nmx,line, re.M)
        out.write(str(nm1.group("ename")).rstrip('\r\n'))
    out.close()
```

But I get the error:

```
File "C:\work-python\transform-asth-b.py", line 16, in <module>
  out.write(str(nm1.group("ename")).rstrip('\r\n'))

builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

here is the input:

```
210 célébrités ou évènements ont été trouvés pour la date du 1er janvier.
Création de l'euro
Afficher le...
...
...
...
```

expected output:

```
210
Création de l'euro ;...
... ;...
... ;...
```

EDIT: I try to change nmx to match \n or \r\n but no result:

```
nmx=r"(?P<ename>.+)(\n|\r\n)Afficher le"
```

best regards

Comment: Does the input really need to be in CP1252? This seems like an odd choice in the modern world, and could be the reason you don't find a match.

Comment: It can be in utf8.

Comment: It *is* in UTF-8 and you are reading it incorrectly, or what? We get a lot of questions where people don't understand encoding, or guess wrong, so it would be helpful to see what bytes exactly you have in the file (just a few -- just showing how `é` is encoded is actually sufficient).

Comment: Notepad++ says the encoding is ANSI.

Comment: That mainly illustrates the uselessness of the Windows terminology (and/or possibly Notepad++) but I guess in your case ANSI means your default locale on Windows. If that's CP1252, then é will be encoded as the byte 0xe9 hex.

Comment: I looked deeper in the menu and it's ANSI(1252).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading a single line at a time, there is no way for a regex to match on a previous line you have read and then forgotten.

If you read a group of lines, you can apply a regex to the collection of lines, and the multiline flag will do something useful. But your current code should probably simply search for `r'^Afficher le\.\.\.'` and use the state machine (`start == 0` or `start == 1`) to do this in the right context.

Answer (score 5):

In this statement:

```
nm1 = re.search(nmx,line, re.M)
```

you get an NoneType object (nm1 = None), because no matches were found. So make more investigation on the nmx attribute, why you get no matches in the regex.

By the way if it´s possible to get a NoneType object, you can avoid this by preventing a NoneType:

```
If nm1 is not None:
   out.write(str(nm1.group("ename")).rstrip('\r\n'))
else:
    #handle your NoneType case
```

Comment: It does work whatever I try to modify nmx attribute.

Comment: can you explain in more detail, how the input and output file should look like? Between "210 célébrités ou évènements ont été trouvés pour la date du 1er janvier." and "Afficher le..." every textline thats end with \n or \n\r has to be in the output file?

Comment: I solved the problem by storing the previous line in a variable and join with the line currently being processed.